# Yarn job memory untilization

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I've ran my hadoop job, how can I get the total memory and CPU usage of that application. I've seen it on log and resource manager web page but I didn't get it.
I can't find counters under job in RM UI.
Is it possible? Can I get it per job execution or on per application, and can I get it per node usage or total usage?

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

The required info should show up on ResourceManager UI, you can also try `yarn top` command to get details.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In Resource manager UI, navigate to Applications, click on the applicationId. for this application, check aggregate resource allocation mentioned in MB-seconds and vcore-seconds, divide these numbers by Elapsed time(in seconds) shown in the same UI, the result will be the total amount of memory/cpu allocated for this application.